# How to update a TeamCity build parameter using REST+cURL

Tags: windows, rest, curl, command-line, teamcity

I have a configuration parameter called "testing" in one of my build configurations in TeamCity. After taking a look at the TeamCity REST API doc [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin#RESTAPIPlugin-BuildConfigurationAndTemplateSettings) I could get information about this parameter using the following cURL command line commands on Windows:

```
(1) curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic (...)" http://teamcity:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt7/parameters
(2) curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic (...)" http://teamcity:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt7/parameters/testing
```

Response:

```
(1) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><property name="testing" value="11"/></properties>
(2) 11
```

But then, when I try to update this "testing" build parameter using the following command, I get an error message:

```
curl -X PUT -d "1" -H "Authorization: Basic (...)" http://teamcity:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt7/parameters/testing
```

Response:

```
Error has occurred during request processing (Unsupported Media Type).
Error: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
Not supported request. Please check URL, HTTP method and transfered data are correct.
```

I already successfully use a similar command to update the buildNumberCounter setting of the same build configuration:

```
curl -X PUT -d "1" -H "Authorization: Basic (...)" http://teamcity:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt7/settings/buildNumberCounter
```

That's why I thought I can do the same with a build parameter in a similar way. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

I managed to update the "testing" build parameter with value "1" using Fiddler. The request I composed had the following content:

- Request: `PUT`
- URL: `http://teamcity:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt7/parameters/testing`
- Request headers: `Authorization: Basic (...)`
- Request body: `1`

So the problem with my cURL command above is probably somewhere around the **-d "1"** option. But where?

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm not sure if that makes any difference, but I use [this](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.28.1) cURL build on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fixing the failing cURL command, as a workaround, we use now [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) to compose and send the REST request to TeamCity.

The script that needs to be fed to node.exe is as follows:

```
// Equivalent cURL command:
// curl -X PUT -d "1" -H "Authorization: Basic (...)" http://teamcity:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt7/parameters/testing

var http = require('http'),
    options = {
        hostname: 'teamcity',
        port: 8080,
        path: '/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt7/parameters/testing',
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic (...)' }
    },
    req;

req = http.request(options, function(res) { });

// write data to request body
req.write('1');
req.end();
```

Although the workaround works perfectly, I would still like to know what's wrong with the above cURL command?

Answer (score 1):

For parameters that are non-XML like the one you are asking about, just add:
 --Header "Content-Type: text/plain"

For parameters that are XML then you'll want to switch that to:
 --Header "Content-Type: application/xml"

Answer (score 1):

I was having a hard time figuring this out too but I found the answer. Instead of using -d and -H at the front. Use --data and --header at the end as shown below . I found this in the TeamCity docs buried in a ["click to expand" example](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-Examples).

Set build number counter:

```
curl -v --basic --user <username>:<password> --request PUT http://<teamcity.url>/app/rest/buildTypes/<buildTypeLocator>/settings/buildNumberCounter --data <new number> --header "Content-Type: text/plain"
```

Set build number format:

```
curl -v --basic --user <username>:<password> --request PUT http://<teamcity.url>/app/rest/buildTypes/<buildTypeLocator>/settings/buildNumberPattern --data <new format> --header "Content-Type: text/plain"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `REST API` expect `XML` as input, add

```
-H "Content-type:text/xml"
```

and put XML as input. If you have a `XML` file `file.xml` :

```
curl -d "@/path/to/file.xml" -H "Content-type:text/xml" (...)
```

Comment: I found this in the TeamCity REST API doc: `Build configuration parameters: GET/DELETE/PUT http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/<buildTypeLocator>/parameters/<parameter_name> (accepts/produces text/plain)`  And also see my update above, I managed to update the parameter with Fiddler without manually setting the content type to XML.

Comment: That quote actually essentially has the answer spelled out by specifying the content type that is required. You just need to put that into the header. See my answer below.